# How can I fix a freezing Explorer?

Tags: windows, freeze, windows-explorer

Windows Explorer will occasionally freeze for 10-15 seconds when I try to run a shortcut or launch a document.  This happens mostly when I am offline and on battery (e.g. working on the train).  During the freeze the load on the system is low, the disk is idle, and I can still switch between windows using ALT-Tab and the task manager.  I have no active network shares (`net use` displays `There are no entries in the list`) and when the freeze occurs the wireless and wired network interfaces are powered off.  I've read the advice offered in response to [one](https://superuser.com/questions/26856/how-do-i-identify-what-is-freezing-explorer) and [another](https://superuser.com/questions/12995/how-to-diagnose-windows-explorer-frequent-freezes) similar question, but it didn't help.

Comment: It could be a combination of going to battery throttling down CPU cycles with and crappy Explorer extensions like a flaky thumbnail provider or context menu item. No other program seem affected?

Comment: How exactly are you running/launching? If you are right-clicking and waiting for the context menu, that points in the direction of context menu extensions. If not, that's one less avenue to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Some notebooks have shock protection. Lenovos specifically have this feature, but I know other vendors do as well.

When the laptop encounters bumps or jolts (like it would on a train) it stops the hard drive for a few seconds to protect it.  This does not affect programs that are already loaded into memory.

What make and model of laptop do you have? I suspect it has this feature installed.

Comment: Nice idea!  The laptop is an Acer TravelMate 8215LMi.  I guess however I would have notices, because when the shock protection is activated a bubble appears indicating the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Please set `High Performance` or change your battery's energy plan to the highest before trying something else.

Answer (score 0):

The disk has spun down and it takes a while to spin back up. Try an SSD!

Or, change your power settings to never spin down the drive.

Or, when you are working on the train, run some program that accesses the drive periodically (once per minute ish) to prevent spindown. Utility programs exist for that purpose; if that would be helpful for you I can provide a link.